Etymology of 制度
What is the rough etymology of 制度 (system / organization)? Or how do 制 (system) and 度  (degrees / capacity) come together to form the meaning of system / organization? Specifically, how does 度  (degrees / capacity) contribute to the meanings of system / organization? And what would you say are the meanings of 度, since every time I come across it I commonly have to stretch my creativity to connect it to the word?

If you check the kunyomi readings for 度, you will see that one of them is のり, meaning "rule, law, regulation."
Kanjipedia lists 制度 and 法度 as examples of words that are associated with this meaning of 度.
They list 8 meanings for 度, which I'll truncate here:
1. ものさし
2. のり
3. ほどあい
4. めもり
5. たび
6. 人柄
7. わたる
8. 仏教で、さとりの世界や仏の世界へ導き入れる
(The data on Kanjipedia is maintained by 日本漢字能力検定協会, the group that organizes the Kanji Kentei)

Kanjipedia seems very accurate, but it's a bit hard to parse at my level, do you know of a more English version of this type of website? Also is there a resource on the evolution of meanings of a kanji over time? And to parse the website, everything under 意味 seems to be meaning (seemingly the most important part?), with each number being a separate definition. Are the multiple words for one number simply synonyms to narrow down the specific meaning of a kanji? And are the words following the definition? after the number in 「」brackets examples of the kanji using those specific definitions?

How do you know のり means 則 when it's written in kana instead of kanji?

@Pheonix I think your description basically covers how to parse it, though there's one more level of sorting that you can see in that page. At the beginning, it says 一 ド・ト and then much later on, it says 二 タク. Those are cases where meaning differs by reading, but in the case of this question, only the ド reading mattered. The meaning of のり as "rule, law, regulation" is clear from the fact that きまり and さだめ are listed with it. If のり meant 乗り or 海苔 or 糊, it would have synonyms for those things listed with it.

Also, under https://www.kanjipedia.jp/kanji/0003857100, if my above assumptions are correct, 制度 is listed under the definitions of とりきめる, さだめる, which from my dictionary is telling me means to decide. But how does to decide become system / organization? Wouldn't definitions 2 and 4 on the same website make more sense? Or is this simply a mistake on the website's part?

のりをさだめる is perhaps a way that you can think of the structure of 制度. I'm not an expert on how Chinese compounds were formed, but if you find that insufficient, you'd probably have better luck asking on a Chinese language site for that kind of thing, when the word is borrowed from Chinese.

Is there a particular reason 則[のり] was written in kana that I'm not aware of? Is the word just usually written in kana? Or was it just random. (There seem to be definitions that use kanji, although some also seem to write kanji in kana instead)

For definitions that boil down to individual words, they tend to use a Japanese-origin word without kanji. Kanji do seem to appear more often in definitions that are more like explanations, probably both because it's less important to avoid "defining a kanji with a kanji" when you're writing out a full sentence, and also because it would be annoying to read all-kana sentences.

I haven't studied a lot of grammar yet, so does のりをさだめる mean something like to decide / deciding / decision on a rule / law? Also is there a simple way to tell what word are borrowed from Chinese and which are formed directly in Japanese?

Huh, alright so it seems like writing the definition is just a regular standard for dictionaries, the more you know. Is there a particular reason to avoid defining a kanji with a kanji(and where did you learn of this standard)? A quick chat-gpt query seems to say that it's to avoid using kanji that the person doesn't know, kanji can have multiple meanings making the definition blurry (although kana having multiple kanji and subsequent meanings also seems to be a problem), and to avoid connotations that kanji defining the term might already have. Are any of these reasons true?

This is specifically about the definition of a kanji... It's kind of weird to say 犬 means 犬. That's just tautological.

Wdym can't definitions simply not use the same kanji(Such as here where 度 is defined using both 典[のり], 決まり[きまり], and 定め[さだめ])? And if you mean that we can make a chain A->B, B->C, C->A creating a circular definition, isn't all language circular to some extent? We're getting a bit off of the original topic (although still pretty closely related I'd say), and thanks for the insightful clarifications.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

制度 is a compound of two Chinese morphemes with similar meanings, which is a very common type of compound. According to the kanji dictionary 漢字源:

制 means "to trim down on unnecessary parts" > "to tidy up" > "to regulate" > "regulation" > "the monarch's order"
度 means "any measuring tool" > "degree" > "standard"

The Vietnamese Thiểu Chửu's Từ điển Hán Việt trích dẫn lists the following:

制 means "regulation" > "the monarch's order"
度 means "any measuring tool" > "degree" > "standard" > "regulation"

As for 制度, the Từ điển Hán Việt trích dẫn cites examples from classical Chinese, where it meant "standard" or "regulation":

Book of Han: 臣願為民制度以防其淫
Xu Zizhi Tongjian: 永固自執政為真定尹, 其繖蓋當用何制度? 金主曰: 用執政制度
The Scholars: 近來器皿都要翻出新樣, 卻不知古人是怎樣的制度

This term was well attested in classical literature, so it is no surprise that Japanese writers used it to translate western concepts like "system", "institution" or "regime". These translations were never super precise, so trying to figure out why some words have some modern meanings based solely on the kanji components is a fool's errand. For instance, I dare you to explain why 経済 means "economy", 社会 means "society", 共和 means "republic", etc. Keep in mind that the translators had to take some liberty by repurposing old words to translate new concepts.
Update: To add to @Eiríkr Útlendi's answer, the Chronicles of Japan (Nihon Shoki) merely cited 制度 from the Book of Changes (I Ching):

Book of Changes: 天地節而四時成，節以制度，不傷財，不害民。
Chronicles of Japan (volume 25, Emperor Kōtoku): 易曰、損上益下、節以制度、不傷財不害民。
Translation?/Kanbun-kundoku? according to 精選版 日本国語大辞典: 易に曰はく。上を損【そむ】して下【しも】に益【えき】あるを、節【したか】ふに制【セイ】度【ト】を以て財を傷らざれ
William George Aston's Nihongi: The Book of Changes says :—“Diminish that which is above : increase that which is below : if measures are framed according to the regulations, the resources (of the State) suffer no injury, and the people receive no hurt.”

Update 2: I found another instance of 制度 in the same volume. This isn't part of a quote, but still had the classical Chinese meaning, not the modern Japanese meaning:

Chronicles of Japan: 蓋此、專由扶翼公卿臣連伴造國造等各盡丹誠奉遵制度之所致也。
William George Aston's Nihongi: It is no doubt wholly due to our Assistants, the Ministers, Omi, Muraji, Tomo no Miyakko and Kuni no Miyakko, each of whom, with the utmost loyalty, conforms to the regulations that are made.


What do you mean by morphemes? Just each separate kanji?

Morphemes are word parts. I was emphasizing words/word parts with their meanings, not characters (kanji). Characters themselves don't necessarily have meanings, and both the Japanese and the Chinese have been found liberal with using characters "incorrectly".

@Leebo's answer goes into the meanings of the individual kanji.
In terms of the derivation of the word 制度, a quick look at the 日本国語大辞典【にほんこくごだいじてん】 ("NKD") entry available here at Kotobank shows a first attestation date of 720 in a quote from the 日本書紀【にほんしょき】.
Given that this term is read with the Chinese-derived on'yomi, and given the ancient date of first attestation, we can surmise that this term was likely borrowed from Middle Chinese.

I'm not quite sure what this means and what the website says with my level. Do you simply mean that this meaning is from the same word in (Middle) Chinese? If so, the n the question simply becomes how did (Middle) Chinese get that meaning.

@Pheonix, the NKD entry shown at the link includes a quote from the Nihon Shoki dated to 720.  The Nihon Shoki is one of the oldest long-form documents from ancient Japan that describes the government and mythology of that time.  Much of the document is written in a variety of Middle Chinese that was adapted for use in Japan, a style called kanbun kundoku (just kanbun for short), literally 漢文訓読 or "Chinese writing, meaning [in Japanese] reading".

While written in what is technically a kind of strange Middle Chinese, it was read out as a cribbed kind of Japanese. This is mentioned in @Vun-Hugh Vaw's answer post. ● As far as the derivation of the word 制度 within Chinese, note that this is the Japanese Stack Exchange, where we focus on the Japanese language. For the derivation of Chinese words within the Chinese language, I suggest you'll have better luck posting on the Chinese Stack Exchange.
